# How to say “update”, “updating” and “updated” in French?

Tags: anglais, vocabulaire

What is French for:

- “update” (as in “update status”),
- “updating” (as in “updating status”),
- “updated” (as in ”status is updated”).

I have some data from Google Translate but I know I can’t rely on it.

To clarify I’m only interested in the three words **update**, **updating** and **updated**.

Comment: Di you want to say “update your Facebook status”, ”apply the latest upgrade available to your software” or something else entirely?

Comment: This is not really an answer but horrible as it may seem, in spoken French you can say _updaté_, _faire un update_ etc.

Comment: An easy way I have of trying to find out stuff like this, is putting a popular web app/social networking site that uses the phrase you need in French...

Answer (score 10):

You can also use "mise à jour", which is a more formal translation, but less frequently used.

> Mettre à jour votre statut
>
> Mise à jour de votre statut
>
> Votre statut a été mis à jour.

Comment: I upvoted. But less frequently used than *what*?  These are the most frequently used terms of any, in my experience.

Comment: Modifier, as goto said, will be used more often in non formal contexts.

Answer (score 4):

> To clarify I’m only interested in the three words update, updating and updated.

I imagine the context is a software with a button "Update" that changes itself in "Updating" when clicked, and then changes to "Updated" when the update process is finish.

In such a context, a correct translation would be:

update => "Mettre à jour" (beware of the accent on the a) "

updating => "En cours de mise à jour", or if you have a moving icon close to the message, you can only use "Mise à jour" ("en cours" meaning "in progress")

updated => "Mis à jour"

You can also use the verb "Modifier" which actually means "change" but may be correct, depending on your context.

update => "Modifier"

updating => "En cours de modification"

updated => "Modifié"

Answer (score 3):

I am a web developper. In my company we always use

> Modifier votre statut
>
> Modification de votre statut
>
> Votre statut a été modifié

Answer (score 2):

> To clarify I’m only interested in the three words *update*, *updating* and *updated*.

You seem under the impression that word are translatable on a one by one basis, without taking the context into account.  Both assumptions are false.  You often have to take the context into account to chose the right translation of a word.  And the idiomatic way to express something may need to modify the structure of the sentence so that it is not possible to find the translation of a given word; that's especially true in the case of verbal forms.

As a verb form *update* would have to be translated as a form of "mettre à jour", which one would depend on what form you think *update* is.  As a noun, it would be "mise à jour".

*Updating* is a form of the verb *to update*, and a difficult one to translate without context because it has no direct equivalent.  "En train de mettre à jour" or "mettant à jour".

*Updated* is easy, assuming it is the part participle, it is "mis à jour" (but pay attention that "mis" may have to be modified to agree in gender and number with what it refers to).

See the other answers for more contextual translations, those are assuming a context and if the assumed context is the right one, they are better than what I wrote above.